# How to pass array dynamically to a variable in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar/issues/241

Here it is written as

you can change the default date color by pushing the days to daysConfig and passing dayConfig: { marked: true}
and then you can change the color with .marked class css and also you can pass with the 'cssClass' key

```
daysConfig.push({
date: new Date(item),
marked: true
});

DayConfig {
date: Date;
marked?: boolean;
disable?: boolean;
title?: string;
subTitle?: string;
cssClass?: string;
}
```

here's the interface of daysConfig

When i tried like this

```
 options: CalendarComponentOptions = {
    from: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
    pickMode: 'multi',

    daysConfig: [
      {
        date:new Date(this.absentdate[0]),
        marked:true,
        cssClass: 'my-cal'
      },
      {
        date:new Date(this.absentdate[1]),
        cssClass:'my-cal',
       marked:true
      },
      {
        date:new Date(this.absentdate[2]),
       cssClass:'my-cal',
        marked:true
      }
    ],

  };
```

it worked

But i have an array of absent_date as

```
 absentdate :string[]=['2020-01-03', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-28'];
```

which keeps on varying according to the month.How can i change the hardcoded value to the absent dates that i  have given in the array.Please help me.

T Template ::

```
<ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
                  (change)="onChange($event)"
                  [options]="options"
                  type="string"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                  readonly="true"

                  >
    </ion-calendar>
```

Comment: What's your `daysConfig` length based on?

Comment: it keeps on varying according to scenarious .different on different months

Comment: Is it linked to absent[] length and order of date?

Comment: yes linked to absent[] length

Comment: You mean daysConfig[] length = absent[] length?

Comment: yes  Mridul daysConfig[] length =absent[]length but it varys dynamically according to each month.For this case i have hardcode.

Comment: that's what i'm asking, there has to be some order according to which you can assign date to each entry.

Comment: Get all the absent days at once in an array, and assign it to the `daysConfig`. Yes, absent days vary depends on month, but you can prepare a overall absent days list (may be in a year) and configure it.

Comment: @Santosh V I have sorted absent days based on months by a http post request.But i cant assign it.Can you give me a code snippet on how to do.here they have given some samples. this.https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar.But i couldnt do any thing .can you please help me

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XPSqia37 .Here is my ts file

Comment: @varundhariyal I have posted my typescript file here

Comment: I want to see template code.

Comment: @varundhariyal I have added the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the following format for options

```
options: CalendarComponentOptions = {
    from: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
    pickMode: 'multi',
    daysConfig: []
};
```

Next, you can loop through the absentdate[] and push each data set into the options as shown below.

```
absentdate.forEach(element => {
    var data = {
        date:new Date(element), //can give custom data
        marked:true, //can give custom data
        cssClass: 'my-cal' //can give custom data
    }
    options.daysConfig.push(data)
})
```

Note: This might sort the data sometimes. if you do not want the sort, you can use the below line instead of push. It will insert the data at the end of the array every iteration

```
options.daysConfig.splice(options.daysConfig.length, 0, data)
```

This should provide following output. Let me know if this was what you were looking for :)

```
{ from: 1999-12-31T18:30:00.000Z,
  pickMode: 'multi',
  daysConfig:[ 
      { 
          date: 2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z,
          marked: true,
          cssClass: 'my-cal' 
      },
      { 
          date: 2020-01-04T00:00:00.000Z,
          marked: true,
          cssClass: 'my-cal' 
      },
      { 
          date: 2020-01-28T00:00:00.000Z,
          marked: true,
          cssClass: 'my-cal' 
      } 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: thanks Srikar B S this worked fabulously.Thank you so much.